# Sonarqube widget runtime configuration of single select choices

Tags: sonarqube

I have a widget, lets say it looks something like this:

```
@UserRole(UserRole.USER)
@Description("I am a sample widget")
@WidgetCategory({"Global"})
@WidgetProperties({
    @WidgetProperty(key = "widgetTitle"),
    @WidgetProperty(key = "mySelect", type = WidgetPropertyType.SINGLE_SELECT_LIST, defaultValue = "a",
        optional = false, options = {
        "a", "b", "c"
    })
})
public class MySuperDuperWidget
    extends AbstractRubyTemplate
    implements RubyRailsWidget
{
```

This totally works, and I get a dropdown with "a", "b", and "c". But what if these are not fixed choices? I want to do some logic (say make a rest call to another server and find out which possible choices are valid today), and populate this dropdown at runtime.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported - and we have no plan to support this for the moment.

Comment: What is the workaround? Roll your own template outside of the normal widget plan?